# Timestamp format from array type column (query from PySpark) is different from what I get from browser

Tags: pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table have an array type column called `history`.

`select history from table`

When I query from snowflake browser, it's showing

```
[{
  "expirydate": "2019-01-23 23:59:59.000 -0700" 
}]
```

when I run same query from PySpark, it's showing

```
[Row(history=u'[{"expirydate":"-0700 2019-09-23 23:59:59.000"}]')]
```

I tried to explicitly set some session parameters

`TIMESTAMP_LTZ_OUTPUT_FORMAT`

`TIMESTAMP_NTZ_OUTPUT_FORMAT`

`TIMESTAMP_TZ_OUTPUT_FORMAT`

`TIMESTAMP_OUTPUT_FORMAT`

through both `options()` method and `alter session set` query, but nothing helped.

I expect query result I get from PySpark is the same as I see from Snowflake Browser

Comment: @Zhemkai, do you mind sharing the type() or typedef()  for both outputs?

Comment: When you alter the session, is this within the PySpark code?  The session you alter in the browser can be different from the session altered during client side in PySpark.